# Comparing current from two 9V batteries

Tags: batteries

I have two 9V batteries, an Energizer and a very cheap Gettop that was bundled with some equipment. The Energizer is down to 7.2V, the Gettop is at 9V. If I connect each of these separately to an LED via a 560 ohm resistor, the Energizer's current through the circuit is 7.1mA, while the Gettop only manages 1.1mA. Can someone help me understand what is going on here. Is the chemistry of the Gettop limiting the current? Is this telling me to avoid the very cheap batteries, or only to know their limitations?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Sounds like the Energizer is alkaline, the Gettop is carbon-zinc.  The two types behave very differently when nearly dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a battery goes flat, the voltage will slightly reduce.  But at the same time, the internal resistance rises substantially.

So even if the battery gives 9V with no load, as soon as you connect a load, the output voltage drops.

So if you're testing how good a battery is, you need to apply a load, and then measure the voltage.

Answer (score 2):

You've just discovered that alkaline batteries are not carbon-zinc!

The unloaded voltage for a 9V alkaline batt will decrease as it's drained, while a (much cheaper) 9V zinc battery will show 9V even when "dead."

Also, a nearly-dead alkaline battery at 7.2V might still supply a hundred mA when shorted (zero volts,) but a carbon-zinc will only give a couple mA or even less.

To calculate the "dead" battery internal resistance, subtract 560 ohms from the VI load resistance, like so:

R(int) = V(open) / mA *1000 - 560ohm

For the alkaline, internal R is:  7.2V / 7.1mA * 1000 - 560 = 454 ohms

For your zinc, internal R is: 9V / 1.1mA * 1000 - 560 = 7.6K

(I figured out this stuff around 1992 while hooking 200 nearly-dead alkaline batteries in series, "bandolier" style.  1.8 kilovolts!  Yes, I did manage to zap myself with it.   Also used a couple of nails to burn my initials into a 2X4 board in flaming carbonization.)

---

Also a secret:

You can recharge your expensive 9V alkalines, but only if the plates aren't yet destroyed.  (All batteries are rechargable.  But the plates of single-use batteries get destroyed near the end of their lives.)

If the batt voltage is still roughly 8V or higher, hook the battery up to a benchtop supply set for 10V output and 20mA current limit. (Or use a 10V supply with a 100-ohm resistor in series.) This will trickle-charge the battery.  If it works, then you'll see the battery voltage slooooowly rise to 10V over hours.  But if the alkaline is truly dead, it will go up to 10V in a few minutes, which demonstrates its damaged plate-area (and large internal resistance.)

Best is to not let your single-use batteries drop below 8.8V or so, which is the point where the battery plates are not just thinning, but being eaten away entirely.  It's possible to thicken the plates and partly restore a well-used alkaline battery, but we can't replace the missing plates of a truly dead battery.

Answer (score 0):

The Gettop battery is what we call "dead".  Toss it and move on.

Note that both the voltage and the current are indicating this battery is dead. 7.2 V open circuit for a battery that is supposed to be 9 V is very low. But again, this is open circuit. The internal resistance has gone up dramatically too, so as soon as you try to load it, the voltage plummets.

This is a great illustration of how batteries should be tested under load, not open circuit.

Comment: :) I would have expected the voltage to be the indicator of "dead"-ness rather than the current though. That's what's baffling me slightly.

Comment: yeah it confuses many people (see Batteriser and David L Jones's comments on it)

Answer (score 0):

Aged battery cells (and the 9V has N=6 series cells) , are as "strong" as the weakest cell, although the internal resistance adds and the capacitance divides by N for the C of each cell.

The electrical model usually drops to 10% of the capacitance and 100 to 100x the internal resistance, Ri = ESR. However, memory capacitance an equivalent RC parallel network can restore the cell voltage over time but with much higher Ri = ESR.  But in reality there are multiple ESR's and multiple C values.

So voltage is a poor indicator of current* time capacity , only a load current.  However if a good rechargeable cell is declining in V due to a constant load, then and only then is cell voltage a good indicator of State of charge (SoC).

Read my answer here [How is it possible a dead old Lithium battery becomes charged after opened?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365417/how-is-it-possible-a-dead-old-lithium-battery-becomes-charged-after-opened)